# PyCharm failed to render image

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter

I have a problem:

[image]

"Failed to render image". Yesterday on the same machine everything was fine and I didn't change a thing (I did update my Kubuntu, but nothing critical), so I expected this to continue to work ...

Has anyone every experienced this with PyCharm Professional (edu version) on Kubuntu (20.04  if relevant) and Jupyter notebooks?

Comment: Does Jupyter Notebook produce better logs than that? I am not sure that is going to be enough to help readers understand your problem.

Comment: If you are stuck, you could install a virtual machine (e.g. VirtualBox) and install Jupyter Notebook from scratch. That might get you up and running quickly.

Comment: odd enough: after I opened the notebook in a browser *once* I don't get this message anymore ..

Answer (score 0):

To those who are facing the same issue, I simply closed and reopened PyCharm, which solved the problem.